# QWebEngineView and HTTPS, no content

Tags: javascript, qt, https, qtwebengine

Using QWebEngineView (Qt 5.8 Windows 10, QtCreator 4.2.2, the same problem also appears in Fedora 26) to access an HTTPS site, I always get an empty document once the download has been completed. Searching the internet, it appears this is a fairly common problem, but I have yet to find a solution to the problem.

I assume I need to do something regarding SSL and/or javascript (the site I need to connect to, specifically uses javascript to do everything) but I haven't figured out how to do it yet.

SSL is working fine in other part of the program, both on Windows and in Fedora.
Looking at the source of the downloaded document, reveals that nothing is contained in the page; connecting to the load* signals, there is evidence that some elements are being downloaded and redirects are followed.

Comment: Maybe you have no OpenSSL libraies...

Comment: I do have OpenSSL libraries. They are even used, correctly in a different part of the program. Fully functional.

Comment: I got this working using QWebView (WebKit, rather than Chromium) using Qt 5.7 on my box at home, running Fedora. Unfortunately, Qt Creator 4.2.2 on Windows 10 refuses to acknowledge that the WebKit module is available for any version of Qt installed (5.6 and 5.7 tested). So, I'm basically back to square 1.

Comment: Read this tread: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42725
At end you can find links to WebKit builds for the latest Qt versions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it's not relevant. I have tried both MinGW and MSVC, and only (as expected), MSVC gave me -any- result. I have already tried the latest WebKit builds to no avail.

Comment: Can you show the code, where you set up your QNetworkRequest and perhaps some working (public) URL, this would make it possible to reproduce your issue. What kind of server do you attach to?

Comment: It's just a plain dumb QWebEngineView, with nothing special going on. The only thing I'm doing with it is calling load(). I've tried several servers, all with the same result.

Comment: "to access an HTTPS site" Is your problem in particular or is it a more general one regarding HTTPS websites? If the first can you provide more informaiton on the website you have problems with (beside: it uses a lot of JS)?

Comment: are you able to ping any ip like 8.8.8.8 google ip ?

Comment: @rbaleksandar It's a general problem. In this case I just need access to one particular site, but I tested with others. The problem doesn't appear to be getting connected since it does follow redirects.

Comment: @KimSandra I'm able to anything you'd expect from a network connection except show the content of sites loaded over https in webengineview.